Shift position of photo downwards in ModernCV classic
I'm using ModernCV to create a CV, and I am struggling to adjust the position of my photo.
The code I'm using is:
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, color, final]{moderncv}


\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 



%moderncv themes

\moderncvcolor{green}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
%character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%adjust page margins
\usepackage[scale = 0.8]{geometry}
\recomputelengths

%Personal Data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\born{01. 01. 1900}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\phone{0~123 ~456~789~101}
\email{john.doe@abc.de}
\address{streetno 1}{12345 city}
\photo[80pt][0.2pt]{BEST.jpg}
\nopagenumbers{}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvhead}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \@initializebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}%
  \if@details%
    \def\phonesdetails{}%
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \def\socialsdetails{}%
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \savebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}{%
      \addressfont\color{color2}%
      \if@left\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi%
      \if@right\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
        \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
        \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
      \end{tabular}
    }\fi%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \@initializebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
      {}%
      {%
        \if@left%
          \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi%
        \color{color1}%
        \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
        \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
          \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
        \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}%
        \if@right%
          \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi}%
  % name and title (pre-rendering)
  \@initializelength{\makecvheaddetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvheaddetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}%
  \@initializelength{\makecvheadpicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvheadpicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvheaddetailswidth-\makecvheadpicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \@initializebox{\makecvheadnamebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvheadnamebox}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvheadnamewidth}%
      \if@left\raggedright\fi%
      \if@right\raggedleft\fi%
      \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
    \end{minipage}}%
  % rendering
  \if@left%
    \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}%
    \hfill%
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}\\[1.2em]%
    \usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}\fi% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvheadnamewidth is forced
  \if@right%
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}%
    \rlap{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvheadnamewidth is forced
    \hfill%
    \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}\fi%
  \\[2em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvhead


\makeatother


\begin{document}
%CURRICULUM VITAE
\maketitle
\section{education}
\cventry{2020-2023}{\mdseries  university}{math}{Bachelor of Science}{minor physic}{grade: 0.0}
\cventry{2017-2020}{\mdseries school1}{city}{information1}{information2}{grade: 0,0}
\cventry{2010-2017}{\mdseries school2}{information2}{city}{information3}{grade: 0,0}

\section{exp}

\cventry{2018 - 2018}{\mdseries some stuff}{information}{tasks}{}{}
\cventry{2017 - 2018}{\mdseries some stuff}{some information}{tasks}{}{}



\section{projects}

\cvline{project 1}{something}
\cvline{project 2}{something}
\cvline{project 3}{something}
\cvline{project 4}{something}

\section{languages}
\cvlanguage{language a}{information}{additional information}
\cvlanguage{language b}{information}{additional information}
\cvlanguage{language c}{information}{}

\newpage

\section{Computer skills}
\cvcomputer{program a}{information a}{program b}{information b}

\cvcomputer{program c}{information c}{program c}{information c}

\section{something else}
\cvline{information a}{details}
\cvline{information b}{details}
\closesection{}

\end{document}

This can be of course be optimized, and I am very thankful for every idea to do so.
But my question is the following:
Is it possible to move only the image downwards so that the information on the left-hand side (indicated with green lines in the uploaded picture) is at exactly the same height as the image (with red lines)?


You could use a \raisebox{...}{...} to move the image up and down as needed:
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, color, final]{moderncv}


\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 



%moderncv themes

\moderncvcolor{green}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
%character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%adjust page margins
\usepackage[scale = 0.8]{geometry}
\recomputelengths

%Personal Data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\born{01. 01. 1900}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\phone{0~123 ~456~789~101}
\email{john.doe@abc.de}
\address{streetno 1}{12345 city}
\photo[200pt][0.2pt]{example-image-duck}
\nopagenumbers{}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvhead}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \@initializebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}%
  \if@details%
    \def\phonesdetails{}%
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \def\socialsdetails{}%
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \savebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}{%
      \addressfont\color{color2}%
      \if@left\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi%
      \if@right\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
        \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
        \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
      \end{tabular}
    }\fi%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \@initializebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
      {}%
      {%
        \if@left%
          \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi%
        \color{color1}%
        \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
        \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
          \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
        \smash{\raisebox{-2.5cm}{\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}}%
        \if@right%
          \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi}%
  % name and title (pre-rendering)
  \@initializelength{\makecvheaddetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvheaddetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}%
  \@initializelength{\makecvheadpicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvheadpicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvheaddetailswidth-\makecvheadpicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \@initializebox{\makecvheadnamebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvheadnamebox}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvheadnamewidth}%
      \if@left\raggedright\fi%
      \if@right\raggedleft\fi%
      \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
    \end{minipage}}%
  % rendering
  \if@left%
    \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}%
    \hfill%
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}\\[1.2em]%
    \usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}\fi% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvheadnamewidth is forced
  \if@right%
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}%
    \rlap{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvheadnamewidth is forced
    \hfill%
    \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}\fi%
  \\[2em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvhead


\makeatother


\begin{document}
%CURRICULUM VITAE
\maketitle
\section{education}
\cventry{2020-2023}{\mdseries  university}{math}{Bachelor of Science}{minor physic}{grade: 0.0}
\cventry{2017-2020}{\mdseries school1}{city}{information1}{information2}{grade: 0,0}
\cventry{2010-2017}{\mdseries school2}{information2}{city}{information3}{grade: 0,0}

\section{exp}

\cventry{2018 - 2018}{\mdseries some stuff}{information}{tasks}{}{}
\cventry{2017 - 2018}{\mdseries some stuff}{some information}{tasks}{}{}



\section{projects}

\cvline{project 1}{something}
\cvline{project 2}{something}
\cvline{project 3}{something}
\cvline{project 4}{something}

\section{languages}
\cvlanguage{language a}{information}{additional information}
\cvlanguage{language b}{information}{additional information}
\cvlanguage{language c}{information}{}

\newpage

\section{Computer skills}
\cvcomputer{program a}{information a}{program b}{information b}

\cvcomputer{program c}{information c}{program c}{information c}

\section{something else}
\cvline{information a}{details}
\cvline{information b}{details}
\closesection{}

\end{document}



If I understand it correctly, you want to change the “rendering” part: do
  % rendering
  \if@left%
    \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}\\[1.2em]
    \usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}\hfill
    \smash{\usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}}%
  \fi

instead of the current
  % rendering
  \if@left%
    \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}%
    \hfill%
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}\\[1.2em]%
    \usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}\fi


